# Reformatting contract to one line for solc: really necessary?

Tags: solidity

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contract-Tutorial#compiling-your-contract

Is that really necessary? Is there no option such that the compiler can do this itself at compiletime?